# NO result found error

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Hi my site name is [Stack](http://stackstore.in/). I just added some content with image.When I logged out from drupal  its not showing and giving message like no result found. But it is showing with image when I logged in to drupal. What is the problem? is my file path is wrong?.

Comment: so is it the image,that is not being shown when u logged out..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check **persmissions** for anonymous users (admin/people/permissions) and/or **clear all caches** (admin/config/development/performance) if there are no permission issues.

Answer (score 2):

I can't leave a comment so I'm posting this as an answer, sorry.
The "Extra" menu in the footer of your page is editable by anonymous users. Make sure sure you uncheck "anonymous user" on the "Administer menus and menu items" permission.

Comment: sorry for that .thank you so much .